# Get subset/filter of OrderedMap

Tags: immutable.js

Filter/Get Subest OrderedMap by list of allowed values

Set:

`const allowed = ['item1', 'item3'];`

OrderedMap

```
{
  item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item2: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
  item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
}
```

filteredorderedMap

```
{
 item1: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' },
 item3: { key: 'sdfd', value:'sdfd' }
}
```

Slice, skip methods gives value based on a range of key.
Or can we Select and Delete using deleteAll Method

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using a custom predicate with [`OrderedMap#filter`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/filter):

```
function keyIn(...keys) {
  var keySet = Immutable.Set(keys); 
  return function (v, k) {
    return keySet.has(k);
  }
}

var data = Immutable.Map({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 });
data.filter(keyIn('a', 'c')); // pick
// Map { a: 1, c: 3 }
data.filterNot(keyIn('a', 'c')); // omit
// Map { b: 2, d: 4 }
```

https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Predicates#pick--omit